# Google AdMob TBannerAd LoadAd exception after upgrading to Delphi v10.2.3

Tags: android, delphi, admob, firemonkey

My application was originally written using Delphi v10.2.2 and TBannerAd worked just fine.

Without any code changes and after upgrading Delphi to v10.2.3 (by installing over the existing v10.2.2 using the ISO without changing anything in the installation dialogs), calling TBannerAd's "LoadAd" method started triggering this exception:

> Project myproject.apk raised exception class EJNIException with message
>   'java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 4323000
>   but found 7095000. You must have the following declaration within the
>   < application > element: < meta-data
>   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
>   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" / >'.

I reviewed the AndroidManifest.xml file and indeed the "7095000" value is used, but I don't know why/how delphi uses this value. Rebuilding the project generates a new AndroidManifest.xml file with the "7095000" value, so I can't directly edit the XML file as a work-around.

What causes this? Is it some setting or SDK path that changed due to the upgrade? (I tried searching but couldn't find anything relevant)

Things I tried:

- Completely uninstalling the application and running it again from Delphi (on a real device, a Galaxy note 4).
- Under options, changing the NDK API location and C++ Builder NSK Library paths from "\platforms\android-14" to "\platforms\android-19".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tokyo 10.2.3 has updated Google Play Services and its libraries.

Applications created with old version don't automatically update the libraries to new ones shipped with 10.2.3 release.

To update the libraries go to Project Manager -> Android -> Android SDK xxx -> Libraries and select "Revert System Files to Default" from the popup menu.

[image]

After reverting list of included libraries should be

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this triggered another issue that required me to open another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042552/android-libraries-revert-system-files-to-default-after-delphi-v10-2-2-to-v10-2

Comment: Please check added image with list of reverted libraries. It seems that you have extra google-play-services library in your project. Try disabling that one.

Comment: You are right, I found an extra "google-play-services.dex.jar", disabling it fixed the issue. Interesting that the "Revert System Files to Default" left this entry.

Comment: It might be something specific to your project. It worked on my projects, but I don't remember with which Delphi version they were originally created.