# Android Libraries "Revert System Files to Default" after Delphi v10.2.2 to v10.2.3 upgrade broke compliation

Tags: android, delphi

After upgrading Delphi from v10.2.2 to v10.2.3, the TBannerAd banner raised exception when trying to call the LoadAd method.

After understanding that "Tokyo 10.2.3 has updated Google Play Services and its libraries." ([Google AdMob TBannerAd LoadAd exception after upgrading to Delphi v10.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038757/google-admob-tbannerad-loadad-exception-after-upgrading-to-delphi-v10-2-3)), I tried the suggested fix of "Reverting System Files to Default" by right-clicking the Android Libraries node in the Project manager.

However, doing so broke compilation, returning this error:

```
[Exec Error] The command "PATH {my entire path} & "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\27.0.2\dx.bat" --dex --output="Z:\Tic\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-ads-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-analytics-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-base-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-identity-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-maps-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-panorama-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-plus-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services-wallet-7.0.0.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar" " exited with code 2.
```

I manually entered the command and this is the full error message:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:506)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:336)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:291)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)

The Android SDK listed under the project manager is v24.3.3 32bit.

Did I miss updating something on the Android side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer on the original thread that resolves this, it seems that using the "Reverting System Files to Default" option still left the old "google-play-services.dex.jar" service.

To fix the issue, I right-clicked the entry and selected "Disable", closed Delphi, opened my project's ".dproj" file in a text editor, searched for "DisabledSysJars" and removed the problematic entry.

Comment: It seems that each time I use the revert option it restores the old service, so it's possible something went wrong during the upgrade process itself.